# Homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{7}$ with $\phi(1)=4$. Find its kernel.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{7}$ such that $\phi(1)=4$. Find its kernel.

The solution I have found started with "Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, then for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $\phi(n) = n\phi(1) =4n$.

What I understand in that sentence is, $\phi(n)= \phi(n(1)) =\phi(n) \phi(1) =n\phi(1) =4n$.

But isn't it that that the binary operation is addition? Should we instead have $\phi(n -1 + 1) = \phi(n-1) +_{7} \phi(1)$?

Also, if we say $\phi(1)=4$, do we also mean that $\phi(n) = n$ (mod 7) except for $n=1$?

Comment: In a ring $R$, if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in R$ we often write $nr$ for $n$-times addition of $r$(where we define $0r = 0, (-n)r = -(nr)$ for nonpositive integers). We have $\phi(n) = \phi(1+1+\cdots+1) = \phi(1)+\phi(1)+\cdots+\phi(1) = n\phi(1)$.

Comment: For your second question: $\phi$ is a homomorphism, so you couldn't have $\phi(n)=n$ (mod $7$) except for $n=1$ because for instance $2 = \phi(2) = \phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=4+4=1$, contradiction. But since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$, it is enough to specify the value of $\phi$ on this generator to define its value for every integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I understand in that sentence is, $\phi(n)= \phi(n(1)) =\phi(n) \phi(1) =n\phi(1) =4n$.

This is incorrect. It means

$$\phi(n)=\phi(1+\dots+1)=\left[\phi(1)+\dots+\phi(1)\right]_{\pmod7}=n\phi(1)_{\pmod7}$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically we have $\phi(n)=4n \text{ mod } 7$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. If 7 divides $4n$, then 7 divides 4 or 7 divides $n$. Clearly the only possibility is that 7 divides $n$. So $n \in 7 \mathbb{Z}$. Conversely, clearly $7\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \ker (\phi)$. We conclude that $\ker(\phi) = 7\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How did you come up with $\phi(n) =4n$?